# Android animation of image view moving and rotating

Tags: android, xml, animation, rotation, imageview

I'd like to make an animation that moves the image view from the beginning of the screen to the end, and each time randomizing the x position. How could I do that?

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="359"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    />
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="100%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="3000"
    ></translate>
    </set>
```

I don't know how to randomize the X coordinate, and also why even though I used 0% and 100% it doesn't really start at the beginning of the screen and doesn't end at the end.
Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the animation start from the top-most(y-axis) part of the parent[p] object and end at the default position, thus the position it would be if it wasn't animated, modify your translate definition as follows:

```
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="3000">
    </translate>
```

If you prefer the animation starting from the bottom, use: `android:fromYDelta="100%p"`

Concerning your second question, you can use the attribute [`android:interpolator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) to define the rhythm of the animations.

For example:

```
 androd:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
```

[Here is a short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkvFZY8x6yA) demonstrating the effects of each interpolator.

Hope this helps.